Can I inspect the VMware VMDK properties of disks used by a Linux guest from within that guest?
We operate Linux VMs hosted on a VMWare ESX cluster. We may provide several disks (VMDKs) to a VM, of different storage types: fast and expensive (SSD) vs. slower and cheaper (HDD).
Is there any way for me to see, from within the Linux VM, what type of storage its disks are?
Information sources such as /proc/scsi/scsi just say they are VMWare Virtual Disks. We install open-vm-tools, but these tools do not appear to provide access to this information.
